# Gstreamer: Passing H264 packet from appsrc to appsink fails with incorrect NAL's when using gst:Buffer vs gst:Sample which works

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Using Rust I have 2 pipelines the first ending with an AppSink and the second Starting with an AppSrc.

Ingest pipeline

```
let ingestPipeline = gst::parse_launch(
        "videotestsrc !  videoconvert !  videoscale ! videorate  \
! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=BGRx,framerate=30/1  \
! videoconvert  ! queue name=queuein ! timeoverlay time-mode=running-time \
! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast key-int-max=25 bitrate=2500 ! video/x-h264 ,profile=baseline,stream-format=(string)avc,alignment=(string)au,framerate=30/1,width=1280,height=720  ! appsink name=sink  "
    )?.downcast::<gst::Pipeline>()
        .expect("Expected a gst::Pipeline");
```

Egress pipeline

```
   
let egressPipeline = gst::parse_launch(
        "appsrc is-live=true name=source caps=\"video/x-h264, profile=baseline,stream-format=avc,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1,alignment=au\"    ! flvmux name=mux streamable=true  ! queue ! rtmpsink location=rtmp://localhost/live/out")?.downcast::<gst::Pipeline>()
        .expect("Expected a gst::Pipeline");
```

Just pulling the sample and pushing it through to the second pipeline works fine

```
appsink.set_callbacks(
        gst_app::AppSinkCallbacks::builder()
            // Add a handler to the "new-sample" signal.
            .new_sample(move |appsink| {

                // Pull the sample in question out of the appsink's buffer.
                let sample = appsink.pull_sample().map_err(|_| gst::FlowError::Eos)?;
                appsrc.push_sample(&sample).unwrap();
                Ok(gst::FlowSuccess::Ok)
            })
            .build(),
    );
```

However if instead of a Sample I use a Buffer using copy_deep (which I assume is needed for a memcpy from one pipeline to another - but I did try clone as well)

```
appsink.set_callbacks(
        gst_app::AppSinkCallbacks::builder()
            // Add a handler to the "new-sample" signal.
            .new_sample(move |appsink| {

                // Pull the sample in question out of the appsink's buffer.
                let sample = appsink.pull_sample().map_err(|_| gst::FlowError::Eos)?;
                // appsrc.push_sample(&sample).unwrap();

                let buffer1 = sample.buffer_owned().unwrap();
                {
                    appsrc.push_buffer(buffer1.copy_deep().unwrap()).unwrap();
                }
                Ok(gst::FlowSuccess::Ok)
            })
            .build(),
    );
```

my pipeline runs fine, but the h264 NAL's seem to be broken and probing the output stream I get the following message

```
[NULL @ 0x11de05440] missing picture in access unit with size 22553
[extract_extradata @ 0x11de058f0] No start code is found.
rtmp://localhost/live/out: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Inserting an h264parse after the appsrc throws an exception indicating it has not received a valid h264 packet - which is transparently passed through.

The reason why I want the h264 is because I want to add SEI messages (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation//video/gstvideosei.html?gi-language=c) with detection data to the h264 packet before shoving it off over the network.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that I did not supply the rest of the structure of the data that is needed

Looking at the structure of a sample

> gst_sample_new (GstBuffer * buffer,
> GstCaps * caps,
> const GstSegment * segment,
> GstStructure * info)

It became clear that segment and structure info was missing. Altering my code now to build a new sample with a new buffer to include the SEI info.

Rubber ducking via stackoverflow :/